# Labels style and position get disturbed in highcharts column graph,

Tags: highcharts

Please see attached image from below link. i am making chart of dummy data for a local project. 
Problem Statement:
My problem is when i set userHTML: true in below code, it move my x-axis labels to up. but when i remove this line, my labels are on their right position. but i need useHTML true and their right position same time.

```
    xAxis: {
                categories: seriesDataMonthName,
                title: {
                    text: 'Month/Year (Charge Date of Service)'
                },
                labels: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<a style="display:inline !important" class="clsCPTTrendingChart"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="' + this.value + '">' + this.value + '</a>'
                    },

                }
            },
```

[image: Image is here. Please see image.]

Comment: It is, probably, because you use some styling which changes the position of the labels. Recreate the issue on jsfiddle or paste your code here. http://jsfiddle.net/o72xdwzg/1/

Comment: Thanks, It is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments. I simply remove the useHTML: true and call javascript function directly in tag. It works for me.